# Compiling C code generated at runtime within Python

Tags: python, c, compilation

I am generating some C code at runtime within Python. What is the best way to compile this code into *something* that can be called from Python? I know that I can do:

```py
import subprocess
from ctypes import cdll
subprocess.run(['gcc', '-shared', '-o', 'tempfile.so', 'tempfile.c'])
main_function = cdll.LoadLibrary('tempfile.so').main
```

But it is a lot of work to solve all the edge cases and portability problems related to this solution. I was hoping this was a common enough issue that it had a standard solution that abstracts the difficult parts away (finding an installed compiler, writing to a temporary directory, handling errors, cleaning up garbage, etc.).

I found that [`weave`](https://pypi.org/project/weave/) can do this, but it is Python 2 only. I am on Python 3.

This is not a question about how to import already-compiled C code. I am familiar with `ctypes`.

This is also not a question about generating different code that can be handled easier. I am familiar with `numba` and `cython` which compile Python code, but unless they have a hidden feature to accept pure C code, that won't work because the C code is being generated by an external tool.

Comment: Maybe CFFI https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#other-cffi-modes is worth a try?